# How to properly texture this cylinder

Tags: texturing

For some reason, this hollow cylinder gets textured differently than a normal cylinder, and it's auto generated as a column, just like doors and windows.
I like the way it looks better than texturing a normal cylinder, but it stops looking good at one point and the texture seems to clip.

[image]

You can see in the left column that at the bottom, it's well textured, but as it goes up, it becomes weird. It's a poliigon texture I applied with nodes. 
What can I do to fix it, or achieve a result like the bottom part of the column?

Comment: How does your node setup looks like? How did you unwrap your cylinder? etc...

Comment: This is the node setup: http://prntscr.com/keba06
I just went to edit mode and pressed unwrap.

Answer (score -1):

In the Edit mode delete the top and bottom faces. As we do not need extra faces here.

With the edge selected. Select the top and bottom and any center edge with <kbd>shift</kbd> select

With the edge selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select <kbd>Mark Seam</kbd>

Now Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all Faces. Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select <kbd>Unwrap</kbd>

Drag and make a new window -> UV Editor

Click on the new button and navigate the image.

Now in the material tab -> New and select the image from drop down

Note : Before you process the above steps. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select Rotation and Scale

[image]

Click on the small dot -> image texture

[image]

Then click the drop down here (find the same texture you have used in UV editor)

[image]

Comment: I can't select the top, bottom and a center edge. How do I do that? I'm pressing alt+select to select all the top edges, so how do I select the bottom ones at the same time?

Comment: Go in wireframe mode or mean time Press H to hide floor and ceiling

Comment: That's not what I meant. In your gif, you select the top and bottom circles of the cylinder, but I can't do that. When I try to select it, I just select a single vertex and not the circumference itself.

Comment: I got that to work. Now, when I go to the materials tab, how do I select the image? Where's the drop down you mentioned? When I press on New, a bunch of options and settings show up.

Comment: @Skyleft check the answer edited

Comment: The "Surface" option isn't anywhere in the Material tab: http://prntscr.com/kec7l8

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I started creating a new project just for this and forgot to turn to cycles.

Comment: @Skyleft hope you got the solution

Comment: Kind of. Doing what you said does texture the cylinder properly, however it's different than how I show it in the picture. Instead of going around the column, it textures it as if it's made of that material, which implies it's the optimal way to texture it. However, I think the way it looks in my image does look a little bit better. It's  not the biggest deal, though, so if I don't figure out a way to have it that way I'll stick with your way.